# Create column based on value from different column Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my dataframe is as below, I want to create a new column based on value of column "a" but the value is from "b" and "c"

```
a   b    c
1  0.1   2
0   3   0.2
1  0.4   5
```

I create a function as below, but it's not working.. any idea?

```
def proba_column(row):
    if row["label"] == "1":
        val = row["c"]
    else:
        val = row["b"]
    return val

result['proba'] = result.apply(proba_column,axis=1)
```

expected result should be:

```
a   b    c  proba
1  0.1   2   2
0   3   0.2  3
1  0.4   5   5
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function compares the row to string 1 (`"1"`) instead of integer 1 , if you replace "1" with `1` , `apply` will work as intended:

```
def proba_column(row):
    if row["a"] == 1:
        val = row["c"]
    else:
        val = row["b"]
    return val
df['proba'] = df.apply(proba_column,axis=1)
```

However , you do not need to use `apply` for such cases , generally `np.where` as the above answer suggests suggests should do it . However adding in another method using [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) after using a `series.map` on column `a` with a dictionary:

```
df['proba'] = df.lookup(df.index,df['a'].map({1:"c",0:"b"}))
```

---

```
print(df)

   a    b    c  proba
0  1  0.1  2.0    2.0
1  0  3.0  0.2    3.0
2  1  0.4  5.0    5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.choose`:

```
df["proba"] = np.choose(df["a"], [df["b"], df["c"]])

print(df)
   a    b    c  proba
0  1  0.1  2.0    2.0
1  0  3.0  0.2    3.0
2  1  0.4  5.0    5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like that your logic is to choose value from column `c` when `a == 1`, else choose `b`.

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In[579]: import numpy as np
In [580]: df['proba'] = np.where(df.a.eq(1), df.c, df.b)

In [581]: df
Out[581]: 
   a    b    c  proba
0  1  0.1  2.0    2.0
1  0  3.0  0.2    3.0
2  1  0.4  5.0    5.0
```

**OR** use [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
In [610]: df['proba'] = df.c.where(df.a.eq(1), df.b)

In [611]: df
Out[611]: 
   a    b    c  proba
0  1  0.1  2.0    2.0
1  0  3.0  0.2    3.0
2  1  0.4  5.0    5.0
```